# Swift 3 Set Operations Subtract

Tags: ios, swift, set

```
var studSubj: [String: Set<String>] = [

    "Juan":["OOP","WEBAPP","MOBILEAPP","XML"],

    "Pedro":["XML","DATASTRUCT","OOP","WEBAPP"],

    "Jose":["WEBAPP","XML","SYSAD"]];

print(studSubj["Juan"]!.subtract(studSubj["Pedro"]!));
```

I'm using IBM Swift Sandbox to simulate the code. The only output i see is (), is there anything wrong with my code?

[EDIT]
I am subtracting to get the unique subjects taken by juan.

Comment: why subtracting from `studSubj["Juan"]`?

Comment: to get the unique subjects that Pedro doesn't have that Juan have. Specifically the "MOBILEAPP".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
print(studSubj["Juan"]!.subtracting(studSubj["Pedro"]!));
```

Comment: @RalphMacalino you're welcome :) if my answer was useful, please vote it and accept it, it will be so clearly useful also for every user may visit your question

Answer (score 0):

`subtract` appears to be a mutable operation, that is it affects the set upon which it's called. To get a new set as a return value, use `subtracting` as @ddb suggests.

For instance, if the OP added the following line to his code:

`print(studSubj["Juan"]!`

he would see the desired output, that is ["MOBILEAPP"]